# Rails Controller Confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller

this is my first post.

I'm brand new to Rails and I'm attempting to learn how to use it. To be clear, I have a brushing familiarity with Ruby. I'm pretty sure I get the MVC structure, but I'm having trouble understanding certain behaviors I'm experiencing.

Just in case anyone learned from the same source, I'm watching Derek Banas explain it. He explains the thing I'm having trouble with around 16:20. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GY7Ps8fqGdc

On to specifics- So I placed this line in my routes.rb file:

```
 match':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => :get
```

and I created an instance variable in the controller using this:

```
  def sample
    @controller_message = "Hello From The Controller"
  end
```

And in a sample view I created, I call on the "controller_message" variable like this:

```
<%= "#{@controller_message}" %>
```

And it works on that one view half the time. Now from what I understand, I should see "Hello From The Controller" anywhere that line of code is placed in a view, right? Maybe I just don't understand how this functions, but I made other view files in the same directory in an attempt to see how controllers pass data to views. They load and everything, but I'm not getting the message from the controller. Sometimes, seemingly inconsistently, the controller message won't even display on the first  view where it worked originally, especially if I navigate around the site a little. To get it to display that message again, I have to restart my server.

So am I just misunderstanding how MVC works, or is my software glitching (unlikely, I know), or what? I'm so confused.

I've heard so many great things about this community. Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help me. I'm so stressed out.

Comment: That's a dismally bad tutorial. Creating a "magic" route such as  `match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => :get` might seem *clever* but opens up any action in your application to GET requests!

Comment: I understand why you'd say that, but I assure you, he's well regarded as a programming teacher. I believe the reason he used a "magic" route was so that he could focus on explaining the relationships between controllers and views before he moved on to routes. The MVC model structure is kind of daunting to newcomers. Learning how all the parts work together at once I mean.
<br/>
However, I'm a fan of learning from multiple sources. So if you want to suggest a good tutorial for a beginner, I'd definitely watch it.

Comment: M. Hartl's Rails Tutorial is pretty decent. He does a much better job at explaining MVC by using the scaffold command instead of this nonsense.

Comment: M. Hartl's Rails Tutorial is the holy bible of RoR! lol

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a view. 

For the record, Derek Banas does explain it using scaffold later in that same video.

Comment: For real, I'm about to watch it right now. I sincerely appreciate the recommendation. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `#{}` in `<%= "#{@controller_message}" %>`is string interpolation.  The usual convention of displaying an instance variable in a view is simply `<%= @controller_message %>`

The variable `@controller_message`, declared in the `sample` method, makes that variable available to the view associated with that method.  By default, rails will look for a corresponding view file that has the same name as the controller method, so in this case it will look for a view called `sample.html.erb` in the `app/views/your_controllers_name` folder

Comment: Thank you so much for the very clear answer. I mean, wow! You explained that so well. I up-voted your comment, but it won't display yet because I have fewer than 15 points.

Comment: No problem! :) . I'd recommend trying to not use too many generators / scaffolding at first, they come in handy once you know what's going on under the hood but can seem like "magic" until you do

Answer (score 0):

Well, to clarify things (because your question is a little vague): rails does a lot of stuffs behind the scene, like relating controller's name with view's name. That is why, in most case, you don't invoke a view to be render in controller's method (Rails does that to you based on file's name). So, would make sense the variables declared in a controller method be displayed only in the view with the same name as the controller method called. If you want to display a variable in a view that is not related with the controller method, you should invoke that view with methods like Render and Redirect, and pass the variables as arguments to those methods.

I.g:

other.controller

```
def edit          
  render "/another_view_folder/example.html.erb", @variable_to_be_displayed
end
```

Another thing:

```
<%= @controller_message %>
```

This is enough to display the variable. The way you were doing was Interpolation (use to concatenate variable with strings).

I hope I can help you!

Comment: Thank you for being so helpful! That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

Rails will implicitly render a view file if it is found in the view path.

So given:

```
# config/routes.rb
get 'foos/bar'


# app/controllers/foo_controller.rb
class FoosController < ApplicationController
  def bar
    @controller_message = 'Hello'
  end
end
```

Rails will attempt to find the file `bar.html.erb` in `app/views/foos` when we request `/foos/bar`. If we want to render another view we need to tell rails to [render it explicitly.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-an-action-s-template-from-another-controller)

```
class FoosController < ApplicationController
  def bar
    @controller_message = 'Hello'
    render 'some_other_view' # renders app/views/foos/some_other_view.html.erb
    # or
    render 'some_other_folder/some_other_view' # renders app/views/some_other_folder/some_other_view.html.erb
  end
end
```

> Now from what I understand, I should see "Hello From The Controller" anywhere that line of code is placed in a view, right?

No. Lets say you add another controller and view.

```
# config/routes.rb
get 'people', to: 'people#index'

# app/controllers/people_controller.rb
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end

# app/views/people/index.html.erb
<h1>The message is: <%= @controller_message %></h1>
```

It will just render `The message is:`. Since `PeopleController` does not set the instance variable `@controller_message`. Ruby will not raise an error if you reference an unassigned instance variable.

The way to reason about this is that the controller in Rails packages all its instance variables and passes them to the view context so that we can use them in the view.

After the controller has finished rendering it sends the rendered template and the program exits*. Instance variables, local variables etc, do not carry over to the next request.

Comment: As to the inconsistency - its not really the intended behaviour but I'm guessing its more attributed to user error than an actual bug in the framework.